# Dell XPS 13 static noise from speakers (only on Windows)

Tags: windows, audio, sound-card, noise, dell-xps

I received a Dell XPS 13 (9350, i7, QHD+ touchscreen) yesterday. It is working perfectly except for the speakers, which start producing a considerable amount of static noise (different from the wide known coil whining, which is also present).

I was thinking that there could be something wrong with the speakers (wrong insulation?) since this happens even if I set the volume to mute on Windows. However, I have installed Ubuntu (from where I'm writing this) and there are **no issues whatsoever** with static noise.

I have tried to disable MaxxAudio and to update the Dell Audio driver on Windows, but the issue is still present. Turning the volume up and down does not help. I have also tried to remove the Dell drivers and use Realtek's as well as updating the Intel Iris graphics to the latest beta, but **it did not work**

It might be useful to know that I have enabled the Fn+F7 shortcut on the BIOS, which "disables all sound and light producing devices" (it turns off the screen, audio and even the power LED). If I use this Fn+F7 the static noise goes away on Windows (and comes back as soon as I disable this mode). So my guess is that insulation is not an issue, since it would also happen in Ubuntu, and the Fn+F7 shortcut would not help.

Any suggestions are very appreciated

Comment: Must be a Windows driver issue?

Comment: Yes, I guess so, but I don't know which one. Tried updating the Intel graphics driver to the beta version and the Dell audio one to no avail

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and have this issue. I found your question when googling to find out more. So can't be a Windows issue.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. The issue was solved for me in Windows many months ago. I have a 9360 instead now, but it hasn't come back.
Regarding Linux, I use Arch with no issues either. However, not everyone seemed to have the issue at my time either so it might just be some weird driver combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the same issue. At first I thought it was coil whine, but then noticed the noise was coming from speakers.

It only happens after a reboot. If I boot from cold, or if put the laptop to sleep and wake it then the static noise has gone and sound is great. It also goes if I disable the Realtech Audio in device manager and comes back again when I enable it.

Tries updating Realtech drivers, updating bios etc. Considering returning the laptop. Let me know if you get anywhere.

Edit: think I might have fixed it. I downloaded the HD Audio Codecs from http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/
I then let the installer run which changed the audio drivers and went through about three reboots. Now I get some static noise during the start of boot up, but then the static stops (when I assume the drive initializes). Hope this helps.

Comment: This solved my issue. After reinstalling Windows, it automatically downloaded a different version of the Realtek driver, which solved it for me. So this is what I'd suggest to anyone else in the same situation. Thanks!

Comment: I have a 5h old XPS 15 9560 and I get that annoying static noise during boot and audio pop when the Realtek driver enters sleep mode. Did you manage to get rid of the static noise during boot?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get my speaker noise/static to completely go away, back like it was when I just got the xps13, by rolling back the realtek audio driver to 6.0.1.7654.
Hope that helps!

Comment: In my case updating did it, but after a clean install I have also noticed what you said. Installing an older version works as well :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, XPS13 9350 i7. I have it configured for Windows 10 / Ubuntu 16.04, and the problem cropped up while using Ubuntu - a video just started playing audible static instead of the proper audio. I've had the laptop for three months or so, and have been using it without much issue.

After the static started in Linux, I booted into Windows; same problem. The speakers would also randomly squawk.

I tried installing the most recent driver from the RealTek site; that didn't fix it. I tried installing the 6.0.1.7654 driver from the Dell web site; that didn't fix it either. The speakers would chirp occasionally, but would also only play static during videos with sound.

I eventually did a clean re-install of Windows 10 from a USB key, which fixed the problem in both Windows and Ubuntu, with no changes to the Ubuntu installation.

Comment: When you did a clean re-install of Windows, did that fix the problem in Ubuntu also?

Comment: Yep, the Windows re-install fixed it for Ubuntu as well.

Comment: That’s really odd — you had the problem in two operating systems, and re-installing one of them fixed the problem in both.    You should [edit] your answer to say that, as it’s an important aspect of the solution (and people don’t read comments).